# Bug? Can not edit my own comment

Tags: support, comments

I am new to bugs here, so I don't know how is the right way to deal with them.
But for some reason in this post:
https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/173013/could-we-put-a-delay-before-new-user-post-gets-downvoted

I can not edit the comment that says:
"So you are asuming most people is evil and ask bad questions to destroy SO, instead of thinking that the least will do that and some will really try and ask things they need? Besides that question, which was not such, was closed. Because it was really bad for the site"

I wanted to make more clear the last sentence, but the "edit" link is missing.
I can edit however other comments, and I can delete this one if i want.

Am I doing something wrong and that is why I can not edit it?

I am using IE8 (corporate reasons).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can only edit comments for 5 minutes.

After 5 minutes the comment is locked from further editing.

If you want the comment to be corrected, you can delete it and post a new comment.

Comment: Ah really? Well I tried to edit it right away. But thanks for your information. I will delete this post. But first could you tell me where can i check what to do when i think i found a bug? So I dont make more mistakes :D

Comment: @Dzyann If you think you found a bug, then you should search Meta. If the bug has not been reported before, then post a new question. :)

Comment: I searched for this bug. I just didn't think to search for "how do comments work", btw it is not as much a duplicate of that as much of an incorrect post.

Comment: @Dzyann It is common practice on Meta to close such bug reports, which turn out not to be bugs, as a duplicate of the canonical post explaining the feature.

Comment: @Bart can I just delete the question? I mean I didn't realize about this. I was checking posts about the comments and i didn't see that one. This makes no sense to be open or answered, i would delete it. But i dont know if it warrants that i flag it for moderation.

Comment: No you can't. There is an upvoted answer, so you can't delete it. And duplicates can be useful signposts for others who have the same question or intend to report the same bug.

Comment: @Bart thanks! I will mark the answer as correc then :) Didn't know it would make sense even if the question was marked as duplicate.